# Python Ошибка разбора парсеров

Tags: python, lxml

Имеется код:

```
<div class="sm gray">
<img class="absmid" alt="Продам" src="https://vestniktm.com/images/typep.gif"> Разместили сегодня (Дата окончания публикации: 18.04.2019 г.)</div>
```

По сути этот текст относится к div.
Чтобы вытащить этот текст, достаточно:

```
date = html.cssselect("div.sm.gray")[0].text
```

Но нет, возвращает None.
Я подумал что оно относится к Img, просто отсутствует завершающий /

```
date = html.cssselect("div.sm.gray > img")[0]
```

Вернуло:

```
<img class="absmid" alt="Продам" src="https://vestniktm.com/images/typep.gif"> Разместили сегодня (Дата окончания публикации: 18.04.2019 г.)
```

Значит верно. Берем текст:

```
date = html.cssselect("div.sm.gray > img")[0].text
```

Но возвращает также None. Что за?

Поменял парсер с lxml на html.parser, но ошибка осталась

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```
tree.cssselect("div.sm.gray")[0].text_content()

# '\n Разместили сегодня (Дата окончания публикации: 18.04.2019 г.)'
```

Comment: спасибо, не знал что такая команда есть

Comment: библиотека xml.etree :)